# let: not found (node spawn)?

Tags: node.js

Запускаю файл test.js.

```
import { exec, spawn , fork } from 'child_process';
  const ls = spawn(`/data/files/test.js` , [] , {
    detached : true,
    shell : true
  });


  ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data.toString()}`);
  });

  ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data.toString()}`);
  });

  ls.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code.toString()}`);
  });
```

Но выводятся ошибки

```
>  /data/files/test.js: 2: /data/files/test.js: let: not found
> /data/files/test.js: 3: /data/files/test.js: Syntax error: "("
> unexpected
```

Содержимое файла test.js

```
let logStr = "";
var fs = require("fs");
```

Comment: Ну да, потому что вы его запускаете шеллом, а не нодой

Comment: А как запускать нодой?

Comment: В `command` указать путь к ноде, в `args` путь к исполняемому файлу

Comment: или написать `#!/usr/bin/env node` в первой строке файла и сделать файл исполняемым